# TPS or FPS games mechanism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, velocity, projectile

I have seen enough tutorials on unity 3D games. Is there any other link where I can learn Unreal Enginer 4.13.2
Thank you in advance

Comment: Is the projectile launched in a gravitational field?

Comment: It seems to be a matter of relative velocity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_velocity

Comment: @Gert Yes, it is launched in a gravitational field. I am assuming the if there is no gravity then the initial and final velocity of the projectile would be same.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't compute this given only the information in the question. I'm not a physicist, but I would want to know two more things before I even began approaching this problem: × What's the acceleration vector experienced by the projectile along its path? × What's the distance from the launch location to the intercept point along the projectile's path? Also, you are assuming that the two paths intersect; you would have to confirm that.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I am more interested in proof of concept. I am a programmer who have started developing games so it was more of a conceptual question for me. You can assume the things that are necessary. And yes, the two paths definitely intersect

Comment: -1. No research effort. Have you tried googling "projectile motion"?

Comment: @sammygerbil yes i did, and it wasn't clear so that is why I turned to this forum. I don't even have an account here. It is my last resort. Feel free to not help brother. it is ok. I understand the policy and guidelines but i dont know how to ask a question even after you have researched enough. It would always be downvoted

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the (recently edited) question is about learning how to program a game engine, not physics.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**In the absence of air drag** (friction), the final velocity $v_e$ at which the projectile hits the target depends on two factors only:

1. Initial velocity of the projectile $v_0$.
2. Relative height difference between *projectile at launch* and *target at the moment of collision*, $\Delta z$.

[image: Launch and collision]

We can show this by means of Conservation of Energy. In the absence of friction, with $K$ the kinetic energy and $U$ the potential energy of the projectile, then:

$$\Delta K=\Delta U$$

Or:

$$\frac12 mv_e^2-\frac12 mv_0^2=mg\Delta z,$$

with $v_e$ the projectile's velocity on collision.

Reworked slightly we get:

$$v_e=\sqrt{2g\Delta z+v_0^2}\tag{1}$$

Here $\Delta z>0$ if the launch position was higher than the collision position and $\Delta z<0$ if the launch position was lower than the collision position.

As said higher up, Eq. $(1)$ does not take into account any energy losses due to friction. Nor does it take into account the kinetic energy of the target, which will affect the total energy of the collision.